# MySQL: ERROR 1064 (42000) on trigger

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Could someone help me with this trigger please to find out what I am doing wrong.

BTW sometime I didn't have this error...

---

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `domitik_db`.`disp_hdw_BEFORE_INSERT`       BEFORE INSERT ON `disp_hdw` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    declare boxId     int UNSIGNED;
    declare unitId    VARCHAR; 

    SET unitId=(SELECT homeunit FROM t_cpl WHERE t_cpl.id=NEW.idhardware);
    SET boxId=(SELECT dispositifs.idbox FROM dispositifs WHERE dispositifs.id = NEW.iddispositif);

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM disp_hdw, dispositifs, t_cpl as tp WHERE disp_hdw.iddispositif = dispositifs.id AND disp_hdw.idhardware=tp.id AND dispositifs.idbox = boxId AND tp.homeunit=unitId > 0)
THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot add or update row: only one same homeunit id for a single box';
    END IF;

END;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 745: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';

SET unitId=(SELECT homeunit FROM t_cpl WHERE t_cpl.id=NEW.idhardware);

Comment: You probably need a delimiter statement before the trigger definition.

Comment: I have already one at the beginning of my triggers list :

DELIMITER $$

and at the end of each trigger : end; $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not declare `varchar` without a length.
So

```
declare unitId    VARCHAR;
```

should be

```
declare unitId    VARCHAR(200);
```

Specify whatever length you want in your trigger code.

Comment: Thanks this work !!
But i have also other trigger without length but with type TEXT and didn't have any problem with them... any idea ?

Comment: Yes `TEXT` data types does not need length but `varchar` does